# Formatting rows in Excel based on duplicates in one column

Tags: excel, format

Is it possible in Excel to apply a formatting (e.g. mark the whole row red) based on duplicates in one column?
So far I was able to mark the whole column that needs to be looked for duplicates and mark all duplicates in specific way. But how can I apply this formatting also to each row of the duplicate in that column?

Comment: Are you using the built in option to "format only unique or duplicate values" in conditional formatting? What do yo mean by apply to each row? Do you want to look for duplicates within a row or compare all the data in a row with all the data in another row?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to select the entire sheet and apply a CF formula rule of this kind:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,$B1)>1
```

[image: Formatting example]